# Do c++ references work like macro substitutions?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
int &r0=v[0],*p0=&v[0];
v.insert(v.begin(),0);
for (int i=2; i<1000000; i++) v.push_back(i);
```

After I insert and add the additional elements is it the case that the whole vector might be shifted to a different memory location?

So what will r0 and p0 return?

If the vector has shifted I'm guessing p0 will point to garbage but will the reference still work (i.e. return 0)? Is a reference similar to a macro substitution?

Comment: Macro substitutions are completely different to anything else. Your code will create a dangling reference

Comment: The vector itself, `v`, will never move.

Comment: Are you sure molbdnilo? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/ states "Internally, vectors use a dynamically allocated array to store their elements. This array may need to be reallocated in order to grow in size when new elements are inserted, which implies allocating a new array and moving all elements to it. This is a relatively expensive task in terms of processing time, and thus, vectors do not reallocate each time an element is added to the container."

Comment: `std::vector::push_back`: _"If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and __references__ (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated."_ Source:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

Comment: Thanks Richard. That helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference is nothing like a macro substitution.

Any operation that increases the size of a `std::vector` invalidates its `end()` iterators.   If the resizing also increases capacity of the vector (i.e. reallocates the underlying memory) the `begin()` iterators are also invalidated.

That means both `r0` and `p0` are potentially invalidated.    Without checking and comparing the results of `v.capacity()` before and after the resizing (and confirming there is no change of capacity) there is no guarantee that `r0` and `p0` reference or point to the first element of the vector `v`.

The strategy used to update size and capacity of the vector is implementation-defined.   Given that your code is inserting a million and one elements (`1000001`), it is very likely that the capacity is increased at some point, and that both `r0` and `p0` are invalidated (i.e. left dangling) - realistically, few implementations of `std::vector` would use a strategy that won't require resizing when adding that number of elements.   So, practically, it is a fair bet that `r0` and `p0` are both invalidated.

The address of the vector (i.e. `&v`) will not change.   Characteristics of data managed by `v` (`v.capacity()`, `v.size()`, `v.data()`, `v.begin()`, `v.end()`, etc) are what will (potentially) change.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I think it's the use of the word 'alias' in reference descriptions that threw me.